# cryptopp encrypted output file is empty

Tags: c++, crypto++

I'm trying to read a file, encrypt the contents and stream it to an output file. When I run my program, I get no errors. Everything completes smoothly, however the target output file reads 0kb, and is empty. I've tried removing the encryption aspect of the function and simply did
 `fs(inputFile, new FileSink(outputFile)`
to see  if it would copy over - It did not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <aes.h>
#include <modes.h>
#include <filters.h>
#include <files.h>
#include <osrng.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;
using namespace CryptoPP;

int main() {

    // read the file and encrypt it
    ifstream inputFile("example.txt", ios::binary);
    ofstream outputFile("example2.txt", ios::binary);

    if (!inputFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Could not open input file"; 
        return 1;
    }

    if (!outputFile.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error opening output file!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "(+) commencing encryption!";
    
    AutoSeededRandomPool rnd;
    byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH]; // 16 bytes default
    rnd.GenerateBlock(key, sizeof(key));
    byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    rnd.GenerateBlock(iv, sizeof(iv));

    AES::Encryption aesEnc(key, sizeof(key));
    CBC_CTS_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEnc(aesEnc, iv);

    if (outputFile.is_open()) {
        FileSource fs(inputFile, new StreamTransformationFilter(cbcEnc, new FileSink(outputFile)));
        fs.PumpAll();

        cout << "(+) encrypted!";
    }
    else {
        cout << "(-) failed to encrypt!";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`FileSource fs(inputFile, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(cbcEnc, new FileSink(outputFile)));`

fs was missing the second argument. It needed to take a bool. Interesting that it didn't throw an error.